# DPST power circuit w/ LEDs

Tags: switches

I have a DPST emergency push switch. I want to use this switch to power and disconnect power for a device. But additionally I would like to have leds as indicators.

This is a schematic I drew for what I'm thinking but w/o leds. The pins at the end are the the vcc/gnd pin for the device being powered(switch is actually 1NC 1NO):

[image]

Is this the best way to approach this problem? What is the easiest way to include leds into this design? Should I provide an external power for the led instead?

Comment: Er, the way you have it drawn, the power supply will be shorted out when you close the switch.

Comment: @DaveTweed The switch is actually 1 NC 1 NO, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is it a make before break switch? Also, if it's DPDT switch what purpose does a drawing showing a DPST switch have (given also that one element is normally closed hence drawn incorrectly)?

Comment: @Andyaka it is a DPST, I was wrong about the acronym.

Comment: So you want the leds on when the switch is Opened?

Comment: @Passerby i want an led for each switch, but only need one on at any time. It could indicate if its opened or closed, doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the power supply for your device - can the LEDs use this power?  I assume from your comments that you want two LEDs, one indicating that the device is "ON", and the other to indicate that the device is "OFF" - is that corrrect?

Comment: @PeterBennett the LEDs can use this power and yes I want two leds like you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fStQn9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I couldn't find a NC/NO swith in the schematic editor, so consider the two pushbuttons as the two poles of your switch.

The resistor values should be adjusted to suit the power supply voltage - 1K is reasonable for 12 volts.  D1 will be on when the device is off, and D2 will be on when the device is on.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't stand the way the writing was overlapping. Also, the "timed controlled switch" makes for an okay nc/no switch symbol.

Comment: wow thanks, this is great and clever way to use the diodes

Comment: @mugetsu and if the voltage is significantly higher than 12v, you might need some changes. You could put multiple leds in series to bring down the voltage that the resistor needs to dissipate

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCgR7C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm sorry but I actually meant DPST

Comment: A DPST won't have enough contacts to make you happy easily.

Comment: so is this just not possible? I don't mind have a separate power to run the leds.

Comment: How will you tell the power that it must power the LEDs?

Comment: i dont know, i don't want to bother with more complex circuit components. Looks like I need to go DPDT instead...